# MQ Client : AMQ9641E error when try to connect to a secure channel

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

I'm trying to establish a secure connection between MQ Explorer and MQ Client (both are Windows machines)
I try everything recommended from the very poor IBM documentation but it still does not work.

I'm getting an error AMQ9641E regarding CipherSpec.

Here is how I used the MQClient :

```
SET MQSERVER=TEST_SSL/tcp/{hostname}
SET MQCHLLIB=C:\shared\MQClient
SET MQCHLTAB=AMQCLCHL.TAB
SET MQSSLKEYR=C:\shared\MQClient\ssl\clientkey
SET MQCERTLABL=ibmwebspheremqmy

C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ>amqsputc.exe SOPHIS_IN QM_manager
Sample AMQSPUT0 start
MQCONNX ended with reason code 2393


AMQCLCHLTAB and clientkey.kdb have been retrieved from my MQ Explorer machine where I properly setup :
- a TEST_SSL channel with SSL activated using a certificate and cypher : TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- a client TEST_SSL channel again properly configuration using same cypher and a client certificate.
```

Can you help me on this?
thanks,
Nicolas B.

I also tried the C# sample provided by got same error.

Comment: What does the AMQERR01.LOG file on the client machine say?

Comment: Unset MQSERVER, it will be used instead of your channel table and you can't specify a cipher.

Comment: Well spotted @JoshMc !